# Insert sublayer behind UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

i'm trying to add a sublayer behind the imageView however the issue is that since it is using constraints it can't seem to figure out the position and just places sublayer in left corner? i've tried to add the `LFTPulseAnimation` to `viewDidLayoutSubViews` but then everytime i reopen the app it will add one on top.

**viewDidLoad**

```
    //GroupProfile ImageView
    imageGroupProfile = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    imageGroupProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    imageGroupProfile.clipsToBounds = true
    imageGroupProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    self.view.addSubview(imageGroupProfile)


    imageGroupProfile.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

        make.height.equalTo(100)
        make.width.equalTo(100)
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.snp.centerX)
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.snp.centerY).offset(-40)
    }


    let pulseEffect = LFTPulseAnimation(repeatCount: Float.infinity, radius:160, position:imageGroupProfile.center)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulseEffect, below: imageGroupProfile.layer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i've tried to add the LFTPulseAnimation to viewDidLayoutSubViews but then everytime i reopen the app it will add one on top.

Nevertheless that is the way to do it. Just add a Bool property so that your implementation of `viewDidLayoutSubViews` inserts the layer only once:

```
var didLayout = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if !didLayout {
        didLayout = true
        // lay out that layer here
    }
}
```

The reason is that you don't have the needed dimensions until after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` tells you that (wait for it) your view has been laid out! But, as you rightly say, it can be called many times subsequently, so you also add the condition so that your code runs just once, namely the *first* time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.

Comment: Okay just seemed like there should be a better wy

Comment: Nope, I do this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: @PeterPik There is one other possibility that just occurred to me. Instead of a sublayer, use a _view_ that hosts the layer. That way, you can set it up in `viewDidLoad` with its own constraints.